# Use System Font in Android Studio Project

Tags: android, android-source

I am developing educational device basing on Android.
I have customized AOSP for our device and built.
Before building, I have added one Chinese font(PingFang.ttc) which I will use in apps.

But i can not find ways to use this font in the app.
I am developing app using android studio. Currently I have font file in assets folder and use.
I want to use the font in system instead of assets folder.

Please teach me how to use system font in android studio project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step #1: Determine the full filesystem path to that font.

Step #2: Make sure that font is readable in your firmware build.

Step #3: [Use `Typeface.createFromFile()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#createFromFile(java.io.File)) to create a `Typeface` for your font, supplying a `File` that points to the font, using the path that you determined in Step #1.

Step #4: Apply that `Typeface` using the same approaches that you are using currently for your `Typeface` that you are creating from the asset.